# Possible bug when selecting tags

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

It seems there is a bug when selecting a tag listed in a question.

Steps to reproduce:

- Select the **Unanswered** tab
- Select **Newest**
- Select any tag that's associated to the question like `C#` (not one of the tags listed on the right side)

**Expected:**

It should show the newest unanswered questions tagged under `C#`

**Actual:**

Currently it shows the [`C#` bounty questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23).

Comment: I do not see bounty c# questions at the link provided.

Comment: Screenshot or it didn't happen.

Comment: @Smithers 4 minutes now, are you okay? Blink twice if you can hear us.

Comment: @adam, questions -> featured - > c# is what the link shows right... isnt that bounty... And browser header says bounty c# questions.. didnt check that..???

Comment: It's okay people! He's back out! Crisis over.

Comment: @random: I do not want to introduce more bugs, than I fix ;)

Comment: guys.. is it a bug or designed like that...??

Answer (score 1):

When you click the tags listed for a question, it takes you to that tags questions page, not that tags unanswered questions page. If you're seeing all questions with bounties, then the last time you had been on any questions page, you must have selected "featured" to view questions with a bounty. The system stores your last selection and presents that the next time as the default.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Select `Questions`
2. Select `Featured`
3. Select `Unanswered`
4. Select `Newest` (unneeded)
5. for a question listed, select a tag for that question **not** the tags listed on the right hand side
6. You should see the selected tags, featured tab, listing all questions with a bounty

To answer "is it a bug or is it designed like that?" I believe it was definitely designed that way. I suspect there is a partial form that handles displaying question previews. While I'm certain the behavior could be changed, I'm not sure it would be worth the effort.

Comment: yshulitelu,  you are correct.. But it seems odd.. remaining activities(like selecting a tag cloud in right pane or selecting child tabs) are  performed based on the conext of the current  parent tab.